# Filezilla not being able to access my FTP files

Tags: filezilla

Hi so filezilla has randomly stopped being able to access my files and i am unsure why, this is what it returns when i connect
Status: Connecting to 167.114.186.68:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (167,114,186,68,131,6).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
Response:   425 Rejected data connection from foreign address 141.255.167.138:26132.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using some mobile connection?

The most probable explanation for your problem is that your local IP address keeps changing.

And the FTP server won't accept data connections from different IP address than the one that originally opened the FTP connection.

There's nothing you can do about it, except for fixing the IP address.